# Can RunWithElevatedPrivileges be used in a PowerShell script?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

If yes, please give an example.

**UPDATE:**

I have a PowerShell script that iterates through all site collections within selected Web application and changes the `siteCollection.Audit.AuditFlags` property. It works fine on my development machine, but the `siteCollection.Audit.Update()` command fails with *Access is denied* error on the production server, even though I am trying to run it as a user who is a farm administrator.

Comment: Why would you need it? Typically, you run power shell as an administrator, while connected to the server.

Comment: Should work, why wouldn't you check that?

Comment: Please, clarify your question, what are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run powershell as an administrator or as your webapp application pool user.

Comment: @chopeen - farm administrator and webapp application pool user are probably not be the same thing, and they probably don't have the same rights to the SQL Server instance either.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question (wheter RunWithElevatedPrivileges can be used in PowerShell or not), but it solves my problem - the script works fine when executed as Web application pool user.

Comment: no, runwithelevatedprivilegs can NOT be used on powershell. why? because there is no underlying impersonation going on for a RevertToSelf call; in simpler terms, powershell is not running on top of an application pool, so the call makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, it CAN be used with PowerShell, even if there is no underlying impersonation. It has effect via setting various SPUser properies (like IsSiteAdmin) in the backround, see details here: https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/further-effects-of-running-code-in-elevated-privileges-block/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it can.

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({ 
    $site = get-spsite "http://localhost/nonfarmadminsitecollection";
});
```

Be careful with that. Since you are impersonating the process account, you lose information about the user in the audit trails.

Comment: This works but mutes the output commands inside its scope. Use Write-Host.

Comment: Be careful..Why? any full reasons about it?

Answer (score 4):

RunWithElevatedPrivs uses the application pool user on regular web apps, not farm admin. If the elevation happens on central administration, then it's a farm admin account. I assume you are doing this on regular webapps, so launch powershell as the app pool acount.