# Change List View Lookup Threshold by code in Sharepoint

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup

My default "Pages"-List-View in Sharepoint has to much columns so it will not show up. The following error is displayed:

> This view cannot be displayed because the number of lookup and workflow status columns it contains exceeds the threshold (8) enforced by the administrator.

I **know** how to fix this using the central administration (like described here: [How to enable a view in SharePoint2010 where there can be more than 8 Lookup columns present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736418/how-to-enable-a-view-in-sharepoint2010-where-there-can-be-more-than-8-lookup-col))

But I want to change that setting automaticly by feature activation with C#-Code. Can this be done by code?

Comment: i dont know how to CHANGE the setting but you should be able to turn it OFF this way:
           
var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["SuperActionHeroList"];
list.EnableThrottling = false;

Comment: That would disable it in the current context, but I need to change that generally so I can view the list in SP-Backend (NO CODE there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**SPWebApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.maxquerylookupfields) determines the maximum number of lookup fields that may be included in a list item query.

Comment: Thanks Marek. But I always get a SecurityException ("Access denied") when setting that value even if I am a farm administrator. Any clue?

Comment: @OleAlbers I don't remember the details but I had a related problem - using the application pool user, instead of the farm administrator, helped. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2154750/95